# Inherent damping in LibGdx DistanceJoint

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I am trying to learn LibGdx and simulate a Spring Mass connection. I am able to define everything correctly and run the simulation but the spring defined seems to have an inherent damping dur to which the oscillations of the dynamic body die out.

I have set the damping ratio to zero but still get the decay.
Can some one explain if this is a bug or am i doing something wrong.

Below are my codes.

SpringMass class:

```
public class SpringMass implements Screen {

private void createScene() {

    trackers = new ArrayList<Tracker>();
    isTracking = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    world.setGravity(new Vector2(0, 0));

    Vector2 boxPos = new Vector2(200, 200);
    staticBox = new Box(world, boxPos, 10, 10, false);
    dynBox = new Box(world, boxPos.add(150, 0), 10, 10, true);
    new Spring(staticBox.body, dynBox.body, world, 100, 0.8f, 0);

  }
}
```

Spring Class:

```
public class Spring {

private DistanceJointDef distanceJointDef;

public Spring(Body bodyA, Body bodyB, World world, float length, float stiffness, float dampingRatio) {
    distanceJointDef = new DistanceJointDef();
    distanceJointDef.bodyA = bodyA;
    distanceJointDef.bodyB = bodyB;
    distanceJointDef.length = length*CONSTANTS.WORLD_TO_BOX;
    distanceJointDef.frequencyHz = stiffness;
    distanceJointDef.dampingRatio=dampingRatio;

    world.createJoint(distanceJointDef);

}
```

}

[image: The cyan curve shows the x Displacement]

Comment: from my experience no physics engine can do that, there is always some loss of energy over time, perhaps because the physics engine state is supposed to come to rest eventually. A perfect conservation of energy like in a perpetuum mobile may not be achievable like in the real world, but you can add impulses to cancel out the loss of velocity as best as you can, plus you may need to limit maximum velocity too. Or simply animate velocity of the body directly every frame to "make" the perfect sine curve you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am actually trying to simulate my problem(a more complex system)  in LibGdx. From your response looks like i correctly named the question that the engine has an inbuilt damping. i will try to add an external force = C*X' which is the damping force. 

Meanwhile if someone could confirm that there is no other way to eliminate this erro :(